# Change of variable question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable, jacobian

Let $D$ be the region in the first quadrant ($x>0$, $y>0$) of the $xy$-plane bounded by the curves

- $y=\sqrt x$,
- $y=2\sqrt x$,
- $x^2+y^2=1$,
- $x^2+y^2=4$.

Using a change of variables, evaluate the double integral
$$\int\int_D\frac{2x^2+y^2}{xy} dA.$$

I'm using change of variables u=$$\frac{y^2}{x}$$

and v = $$x^2 + y^2 $$

Using this, I found the value for what is basically $$\frac{1}{jacbobian}$$

but even with this, I can't seem to solve the integral.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a think about your question, and read it from the external perspective. As it stands, it is impossible for anyone to help you short of giving you the full answer (which is arguably not constructively helping you, since you won't get to learn from your mistake). So, please provide more! "Even with this, .. " with what? If you show us this working, you can get a good answer

Comment: What is the integral you got that you are not able to solve? Please share your work (key steps and the integral) so we can help you.